# set checked or unchecked to checkbox in jqGrid when grid loaded first time

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

```js
{
    name: 'SelectedMaterial', datafield: 'SelectedMaterial',
    sortable: false, align: 'center', width: '250', search: true,
    formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false },
    edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "Yes:No"}
}
```

based on value return from database, set checkbox checked or unchecked

Answer (score 0):

You use `formatter: 'checkbox'` which parse the input data and display unchecked checkbox if the data is one of the following values: `false`, `f`, `0`, `no`, `n`, `off`. All other input values will be displayed as the checked checkbox. I would recommend you to use `0` and `1` (corresponds to `bit` datatype of Transact-SQL) or `true` and `false` (corresponds to Boolean datatype, which exist in the most computer languges) as the input values.

Comment: i am getting data from database for 2 column only,and checkbox column is extra column,based on the value of one column among 2 column,i try to set checked or unchecked checkbox.

Comment: @shyamshankar: Which input data you use for jqGrid? It is not important whether the values come from the database or not. Just the input data are important. Till now you don't posted and example of input data. If you have any problems you can just create the demo in JSFiddle. The demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kvtrtzc5/ for example fills `closed` column based on the input data. You can modify it to your case. You can replace FA locale `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.10.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-fa.js` to youth.